# Why does MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN only work if i add jersey-core-1.16.jar to my classpath

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jersey, shared-libraries

I am trying to write a Jersey client to send requests to a Spring REST service.

To achieve this i added jersey-client-1.16.jar to my classpath as i only needed the services for the client. It is however complaining that it can not find MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN

```
The type javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

It does work if i add `jersey-core-1.16.jar` to my classpath but i dont need this library as i am not writing any REST services. I thought that `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` is part of the JDK (as it is in package `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType`) so i dont understand why it is not being resolved. Is it not part of the JDK?

Comment: What made you think, that is a part of JDK? And you can easily find that out by seeing the Specs.

Comment: I thought that javax.ws.* is part of the JDK. So i definitely need the jersey-core library in my classpath even though i am not writing a REST service?

Comment: @ziggy - javax.ws is in the JEE SDK, not JSE.

Comment: I have the Jboss runtime libraries in the eclipse project as well but will check again.

Comment: Check if you are importing the correct MediaType (import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;). Maven/Eclipse build usually comes with another one imported.

Answer (score 0):

You are mising some jars in the classpath...
add The **jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar**